# Stack showing overflow output but the tutorial shows otherwise

Tags: c++, data-structures, stack

I have written this code using a tutorial. His output is correct but I am getting stackoverflow and memory addresses as outputs although mycode is exaclty same as his.I have declared array size 100 but it's still not working

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

#define n 100
class stack{
    int* arr;
    int top;

    public:
    stack(){
        arr=new int[n];
        top=-1;
    };
    void push(int x){
        if(top=n-1){
            cout<<"Stack overflow"<<endl;
            return;

        }
        top++;
        arr[top]=x;
    };
    void pop(){
        if(top==-1){
            cout<<"No element to pop"<<endl;
            return;
        }
        top--;
    };
    int Top(){
        if(top==-1){
            cout<<"Stack is empty"<<endl;
            return -1;
        }
        return arr[top];
    };
    bool empty(){
        return top==-1;
    }

};
int main(){
    stack st;
    st.push(1);
    st.push(2);
    st.push(3);
    cout<<st.Top()<<endl;
    st.pop();
    cout<<st.Top()<<endl;
    st.pop();
    st.pop();
    st.pop();
    cout<<st.empty()<<endl;

   
   
   
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: This looks like a perfect debugger exercise.

Comment: or an exercise in tweaking your compiler, I dont get this code to compile: https://godbolt.org/z/Krx1fnGPW

Comment: no offense, but almost everytime someone says "it is exactly the same", it isnt ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've run the code and clearly seen that in your 'push' method 'if' condition you missed one more '=', and also I've modified your code a little bit to help you out. Hope you'll find it helpful.

Small updates I made:

1. "inserted {integer}" - msg added in push method.
2. showing top element when popping out 1.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

#define n 100
class stack{
    int* arr;
    int top;

    public:
    stack(){
        arr=new int[n];
        top=-1;
    };
    void push(int x){
        if(top==n-1){
            cout<<"Stack overflow"<<endl;
            return;

        }
        top++;
        arr[top]=x;
        cout<<"inserted "<<arr[top]<<endl;
    };
    void pop(){
        if(top==-1){
            cout<<"No element to pop"<<endl;
            return;
        }
        top--;
    };
    int Top(){
        if(top==-1){
            cout<<"Stack is empty"<<endl;
            return -1;
        }
        return arr[top];
    };
    bool empty(){
        return top==-1;
    }
};
int main(){
    stack st;
    st.push(1);
    st.push(2);
    st.push(3);
    cout<<st.Top()<<endl; // 3
    st.pop(); // pops 3
    cout<<st.Top()<<endl; // 2
    st.pop(); // pops 2
    cout<<st.Top()<<endl; // 1
    st.pop(); // pops 1
    st.pop(); // stack underflow
    cout<<st.empty()<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Good finding with the assignment in `if(top=n-1)` -  It'd also be good if you pointed out what else you changed (and why) too.

Comment: Now you can check @TedLyngmo

Comment: @iam_anirban I already gave you my upvote but I do think it's a little better now.

Comment: I have upvoted but it requires atleast 15 points so ...